# In .php file, when add php code to html, html not works

Tags: php, html

In .php file, when add php code to html, only the html that out of php code works, but within the php code the html not works. But when I delete the php code blocks, the html works again and shows the form as the html.

Please any suggestion why this happening...

My codes are here:

```
<div class="container" style="margin: 2em 5em";>

    <h3>Update Category</h3><hr/>        

    <form action="http://localhost/twlp/mvc_two/Category/insertCategory" method="post">

        <?php 
            if(isset($catById)){
            foreach($catById as $value){
        ?>              

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Category Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="1" value="<?php echo $value['name']; ?>"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text">Category Title:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required="1" value="<?php echo $value['title']; ?>"/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button> 

      <?php } } ?>

    </form>       
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "the html not works"? What happens? Do you get an error message?

Comment: You may also want to look into using the [alternative control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), as this makes reading mixed PHP/HTML code easier.

Comment: how do you visit this page? double click in file-explorer? What does your browser address look like? `'http://localhost/...'`/`'http://127.0.0.1/...'` or `'file://something'`?

Comment: _and_ where should `$catById` come from?

Comment: if this is the complete code: `$catById` _is not set_  so `if(isset($catById)){` will say "no" and ignore everything inside that.

Comment: @ John Conde : no error message, just the form disappeared.

Comment: @ Jeff : actually I am practicing a mvc framework. This form for update data. I could add data with the same html form. The url : http://localhost/twlp/mvc_two/Category/updateCategory, and the @catById from : // to fetch data for update in update form page and to show 
 public function updateCategory(){
  $data = array();
  $table = 'category';
  $id = 11;
  $catModel = $this->load->model("CatModel");  
  $data['catById'] = $catModel->catById($table, $id);
  $this->load->view("catupdate", $data);
 }

Comment: The problem is solved. Actually the issue in $id = 11; I have deleted this 11 id just some times ago.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is from $catById.

I defined an example $catById. Then the page runs well.

```
<?php

$value1=array('name'=>'test 1-name','title'=>'test 1-title');
$value2=array('name'=>'test 2-name','title'=>'test 2-title');
$catById=array($value1,$value2);
?>

<div class="container" style="margin: 2em 5em";>

    <h3>Update Category</h3><hr/>        

    <form action="http://localhost/twlp/mvc_two/Category/insertCategory" method="post">

        <?php 
        if(isset($catById)){
            foreach($catById as $value){
                ?>              

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text">Category Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" required="1" value="<?php echo $value['name']; ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text">Category Title:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" required="1" value="<?php echo $value['title']; ?>"/>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update</button> 

            <?php 
            }
    } ?>

    </form>       
</div>
```